# How to determine what index was created

Tags: oracle

I have been tasked to look at an Oracle database after a colleague has left and I would like to know if he created an index as a B-Tree or a Bitmap.  Unfortunately I can't find the SQL that would tell me this.

I hope it's me being daft - can anyone help?

Comment: get yourself a good IDE like Toad or SQL Developer and you can browse the schema and its objects, and easily determine such things.

Answer (score 5):

You can query the [USER_INDEXES / ALL_INDEXES / DBA_INDEXES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1061.htm#i1578369) views
It may be something like:

```
SELECT index_type
FROM ALL_INDEXES
WHERE index_name = '<your_index_name>'
```